# Function to choose a pivot for quick sort

Tags: c++, sorting

```
int choose_pivot(int lo, int hi){
   int mid = ((hi-lo)/2)+1;
   if((arr[hi]<arr[lo])^(arr[hi]<arr[mid])){
      return hi;
   }
   else if((arr[lo]<arr[hi])^(arr[lo]<arr[mid])){
      return lo;
   }
   else{
      return mid;
   }
}
```

This function should  choose the pivot as follows. Consider the first, middle, and final elements of the given array. (If the array has odd length it should be clear what the "middle" element is; for an array with even length 2k, use the kth element as the "middle" element. Identify which of these three elements is the median. Return the its value.

Is there anything wrong with this function which may not let it do what it is meant for? Am I missing some case for which the function doesn't give desired result?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the function which shouldn't do what it is desired to do?

Comment: `arr[mid] < arr[lo]` and `arr[lo]==arr[hi]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to solve task from coursera.org, you need to use

```
int mid = ((hi-lo)/2);
```

Comment: Still didn't get the right answer :(. Don't know what wrong? Does the above function if modified (mid = ((hi-lo)/2); chooses the right pivot?

Comment: if hi = 1999 and lo = 0: res = (1999 / 2) = 999. 999 is left pivot, because we started from 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that I would consider a fatal error: there's
no documentation with regards to pre-conditions.  In particular,
is calling it with `lo == hi` legal or not.  (If it's legal, the
code has undefined behavior.)  And what do `lo` and `hi`
represent?  Under the usual C++ conventions, which I find work
very well, `lo` would be inclusive, and `hi` exclusive.  But
again, you don't tell us, despite the fact that it is important
to know if we are to judge the correctness of the code.  (The
fact that you do `arr[hi]` makes me think that you've adopted 
the somewhat unusual convention of making both ends inclusive.)

Without such information, it's impossible to do anything but
make stylistic comments (e.g. use `!=` rather than `^` for
comparing results, use `return` with `?:` rather than `if ... else
if ... else`, etc.).

Comment: both hi and lo are inclusive..

Answer (score 0):

1. You should probably use `!=` instead of `^` to compare boolean results for inequality.
2. Based on the textual description, you should be returning `arr[hi]` instead of `hi` (and similar for `mid`, `lo`).